# grails: Href and Src to Subfolder not working

Tags: javascript, grails-2.0

i have the files inside the folder lib\Responsive

How to link this inside the GSP file?

i have used the following code but its not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/Responsive/Responsive.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tablestyle.css"/>
```

i hope it should be from static folder how to refer ?

Comment: Put your js and css under the wepapp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css',file:'tablestyle.css')}" />
```

If css file under wep-app/css/tablestyle.css
.

Comment: its under the sub folder like inside css\subfolder\tablestyle.css ... 
How to refer in this kind of scenario ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css/subfolder',file:'tablestyle.css')}" />